# Replace and Find Regex (newbie)

Tags: regex, replace, find

Hi I need help with two tasks with regex I am a newbie and looked at the various tutorials but cannot find an answer.

1. How do you repeat a word that follows a comma?

   For instance I want to find an replace every occurrence of , and replace it with the word that follows it

   For example: The cat, and the dog --> The cat, and and the dog
2. How do you replace words that start with "i" or "t" EXCEPT the word I

   For example, I want to replace this --> I want (new word) to replace (new word)

Answer (score 2):

1. Replace `, ((\w)+)` with `, \1 \1`.

   `\w` means a word character (typically `[A-Za-z0-9_]`)

   `(\w)+` means one or more word characters

   `\1` means the first thing that appeared in brackets in the first expression (`(\w)+` in this case), and this is repeated twice because of `\1 \1`
2. Replace `(\s|^)((i|I)\w+|(t|T))` with `\1NEWWORD`.

   `(a|b)` means `a` or `b`

   `^` indicates the start of the line

   `\s` means whitespace

   So `(\s|^)` means whitespace or the start of line

   `(i|I)` means a lower- or uppercase `i`

   `(i|I)\w+` means the letter `i` followed by one or more characters

   `(t|T)` means a lower- or uppercase `t`

   `((i|I)\w+|(t|T))` means the letter `i` followed by one or more characters or the letter `t`

   `NEWWORD` is the word you want to replace it with

Answer (score 0):

The first regex is:

```
,\s*(\w+)
```

And you would use the $1 or \1 back-reference, depending on your language.

The second regex is:

```
[iITt]\w+
```

And you don't need any back-reference.

Comment: okay just to clarify, what do I put in the "replace" box on KomodoEditor? I think I know what to put in the find box, but as far as replacing do I need to put a code in there? Sorry I have only worked with literal replacements so far and thus am a bit confused

Comment: I've never used KomodoEditor, so I don't know for sure. Probably, the following for the first:

, $1

And for the second:

TextYouWantToReplaceIAndTWordsWith

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
preg_replace("/,\s*([^\s]++)/", ", $1 $1", $string);
```

This is referred to as grouping and back-referencing. Instead of the $1 you could also use \\1.

A more comprehensive guide: http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Answer (score 0):

This is Autoit code. Maybe it helps to understand

```
$var = 'This is the test, HelloWorld yeah!'

ConsoleWrite(StringRegExpReplace($var, ',(\s*[a-zA-Z]+)', '$1$1') & @CRLF)
```